# scipy k-means algorithm not using all k

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, k-means

I am using scipy library for kmeans algorithm. My dataset was 81k and K was 8613. I used my own algorithm to calculate K. I am not saying my algorithm for choosing K is perfect. My concern is not to chose optimal K.

My main concern is the final result.
After running scipy kmeans algorithm I get the final result with 6995 number cluster. Here, around 1600 K is not used. Let's say the number of K is given more and based on that is scipy K-means algorithm not choosing excess K.

Can anyone please explain why not using all of K?

Comment: I think you need to provide an example. I understand that you can't necessarily upload the data. But to avoid guessing about possible mistakes, you should give an example where it is messing up. Kmeans should not behave that way.

Comment: Can you please paste the code you are using to instantiate the kmeans object?